# How to make an image (that is also a link) larger when hovered over?

Tags: html, css, image, hover, gallery

I've been trying to make my images larger when hovered over but to no avail.
I thought that it might have something to do with the intersection of having a gallery and having my images act as links (because I've got it set up so each image is opened in a new tab upon being clicked), but I can't find a way to resolve the hover issue.

```css
.gallery img:hover {
  border: solid 3px black;
  margin: -3px;
  transform: scale(2.5);
}

div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  transition: .2s;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="img.png" target="_blank"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100.jpg" width="100" height="auto"></a>
</div>
```

No hover effects work, and I can't figure out why.
What have I done wrong, and what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue you describe. The code works for me. Try to clear you cache by reloading your page with `Ctrl + F5`

Answer (score -1):

I found your code to be working for me. I don't know why it is not working for you.

I made a little changes in your code.

```css
.gallery-image {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  transition: transform 0.2s, border-color 0.2s;
}

.gallery-image:hover {
  border: solid 3px black;
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="img.png" target="_blank">
    <img src="img.png" alt="Image" class="gallery-image">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers are not a place to comment that you can not reproduce the issue. Use a comment instead and flag it as `Not reproducible or caused by typos`. Note that missing reputation is no excuse to use an answer to bypass your account limitations.